# Show external sales orders in custom grid in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, admin, sales

I have an external magneto 2 database in which old sales orders exist and I want to show that orders in custom grid like sales order grid.

I followed the https://github.com/joshspivey/magento2-sales-grid link and create custom grid for sales order but order is showing current m2 system but I want to show external's database orders in this grid.

I'm able to create multiple connection by adding following code in env.php

```
'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'magento',
        'username' => 'your_username',
        'password' => 'your_password',
        'model' => 'mysql4',
        'engine' => 'innodb',
        'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
      'newConnection' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'magento_new',
        'username' => 'your_username2',
        'password' => 'your_password2',
        'model' => 'mysql4',
        'engine' => 'innodb',
        'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
        'active' => '1',
      )
    ),
  ),
```

and for the **resource**

```
'resource' => array (
    'default_setup' => array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
    'newConnection' => array(
      'connection' => 'newConnection'
    )
  ),
```

reference - https://blog.imranshakil.com/custom-database-connection-on-magento-2/

I have change `$this->resource->getConnection('sales');` to `$this->resource->getConnection('newConnection');` in sales module but it is still showing in magento's core module but still showing the current system orders. I got stuck. Please help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnectionByName('newConnection');
```

Hope this will solve your problem.